# Check my Proof of the Chain Rule

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Statement: Let $O$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and let $F \colon O \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x \in O$. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set containing $F(x)$ and let $G \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^k$. Assume that $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $G$ is differentiable at $F(x)$. Then $$D(G \circ F)(x) = DG(F(x))DF(x).$$

Proof: We use the Euclidean norm, and the previously proven result that for a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$, $||Av|| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||v||$ (hence linear transformations are continuous). By the definition of the derivative, for $y \in O$ we have
$$F(x + y) = F(x) + DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y)$$
where $\lim_{y \to 0}R_F(y) = R_F(0) = 0$. Thus
\begin{align}
G(F(x + y)) &= G(F(x) + DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y)) \\
&= G(F(x)) + DG(F(x))(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y)) + ||DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y)|| \cdot R_G(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y)) \\
&= G(F(x)) + DG(F(x))DF(x)y + ||y|| \cdot \Big\{DG(F(x))R_F(y) + ||\frac{DF(x)y}{||y||} + R_F(y)|| \cdot R_G(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y))\Big\}.
\end{align}
As $y \to 0$,
$$||DG(F(x))R_F(y)|| \leq ||DG(F(x))|| \cdot ||R_F(y)|| \to 0, $$
and
\begin{align}
||||\frac{DF(x)y}{||y||} + R_F(y)|| \cdot R_G(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y))|| &= ||\frac{DF(x)y}{||y||} + R_F(y)|| \cdot ||R_G(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y))|| \\
&\leq (||DF(x)|| + ||R_F(y)||) \cdot ||R_G(DF(x)y + ||y||R_F(y))||\\ 
&\to 0.
\end{align}
Thus $D(G \circ F)(x) = DG(F(x))DF(x)$.

Comment: Are there possible problems you would think this proof have?

Comment: @macton I think it should be correct, but my book's proof is not correct, so I wanted to write what I think is a correct way to prove it. I guess there is a low chance for errors since the proof is just a computation.

Comment: Your proof is correct :)